# Update List in List view webpart based on url parameter

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, spfx-webparts, modern-experience, classic-experience

Is there any way to dynamically update the list in the 'list view web part' based on the url parameter?

My requirement is-
I have a sharepoint modern/classic web page, in that I have to display list view web part. but that list should be dynamic based on the url parameter(example: listid).

Answer (score 0):

Are you talking about below list view web part?

- https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/use-the-list-web-part-ef0a1b80-f8b3-443d-b04a-1e76c70b5537

If so, it's possible to update its properties via code. For example, we can update it through PnPjs:

- https://pnp.github.io/pnpjs/sp/clientside-pages/

  ```
  public async UpdateSitePage(): Promise<void> {
      const urlParams = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);
      if (!urlParams.has('listid') || this.props.disMode == DisplayMode.Edit) {
          this.setState({
           ready: true
         });
        return;
      }

   const listid = urlParams.get('listid');
   let list: IListInfo;

   try {
     list = await sp.web.lists.getById(listid).get();
   } catch (e) {
     console.log(e);
     this.setState({
       ready: true
     });
     return;
   }

   // use from the sp.web fluent chain
   const page = await sp.web.loadClientsidePage(window.location.pathname);
   const control = page.findControlById('81b84607-7f7a-49d8-b504-957a986d6e07') as ClientsideWebpart;

   let p = control.getProperties();

   if (p.selectedListId == listid) {
     this.setState({
       ready: true
     });
     return;    // the same list, no need to update
   }

   control.setProperties(
     {
       selectedListId: listid,
       selectedListUrl: list.ParentWebUrl + "/Lists/" + list.Title,
       selectedViewId: null,
       webRelativeListUrl: "/Lists/" + list.Title
     }
   );

   control.data.webPartData.serverProcessedContent.searchablePlainTexts = { listTitle: list.Title };

   page.save().then(e => {
     location.reload();
   });

   console.log(control);

   }
  ```

Test Demo:

[image]

The problem is that what we updated is the source page file. Imagic that there're a lot of people are visiting this page, it will get stuck into conflict.

Hence I do not suggest you update this web part property based on URL. you may consider developing a custom web part to display list item based on the passed parameter. MS has not exposed the source code of List view web part, we cannot extend it.

BR

Comment: thank you for providing the insights.